# Rank the search result by click rate

Tags: search-results, ranking

We are using SP2013 on-premise Enterprise edition. According to [Overview of search result ranking in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169065.aspx) the default ranking model have not included the item click rate.

I want to improve the result by putting higher click rate (or number of views) items to higher ranking. What should I do?